# Proper way to parse this line with FasterCSV?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, fastercsv

I have the following line in a CSV file that's giving me issues when parsing:

`312,'997639',' 2','John, Doe. "J.D."       ','                              ','2000      ','          ','Street                    ','City                        ','NY','99999','','2010-02-17 19:12:04','2010-02-17 19:12:04';`

I'm parsing with the following parameters:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(file, {:headers => true, :quote_char => '"', :col_sep => "','"} ) do |row|
```

However, it's blowing up on rows like the one above due to the "J.D" inside a row column.  How do I properly parse that line with FasterCSV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to bend FasterCSV to work the way I need it to with this data so the end result was simply requesting a new dump of the data with proper CSV output.  Thanks for the attempts!

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like your `:quote_char` should be `'` and your `:col_sep` should be `,`. In that case:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(file, {:headers => true, :quote_char => "'", :col_sep => ','} ) ...
```

Comment: That results in a FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError (FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError)
 exception thrown.

Comment: How is your CSV being generated? Are you certain it's well-formed? :quote_char specifies the character that wraps around fields, which appears to be a single-quote in your example, and :col_sep specifies the character between fields, which appears to be a comma in your example. That is the information I based my answer on.

Comment: The problem is that it's not well-formed and I was trying to bend FasterCSV to get it to parse it anyway.  The dump was from a customer and I have since sent the proper SQL query that will output proper CSV.  In the meantime I'm still trying to hack on it.

Comment: "The problem is that it's not well-formed and I was trying to bend FasterCSV to get it to parse it anyway.". You may want to cancel your downvotes on both answers, then.

Comment: They're answers that were untested against a line of data I provided and they don't work.  Therefore a downvote.  If an answer doesn't work, I downvote, if it functions, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  FasterCSV only allows one choice of quote character, and your application needs two.  There isn't a way to do cute stuff like pass in a regex instead of a character because FasterCSV precompiles matchers with the quote character escaped as follows:

```
# prebuild Regexps for faster parsing
esc_col_sep = Regexp.escape(@col_sep)
esc_row_sep = Regexp.escape(@row_sep)
esc_quote   = Regexp.escape(@quote_char)
@parsers = {
  :any_field      => Regexp.new( "[^#{esc_col_sep}]+",
                                 Regexp::MULTILINE,
                                 @encoding ),
  :quoted_field   => Regexp.new( "^#{esc_quote}(.*)#{esc_quote}$",
                                 Regexp::MULTILINE,
                                 @encoding ),
  ...
}
```